# Use values from an array, key as subtring of a column in awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file named order.csv, data is like

```
"Company","New Add Date"
"ELECTRICAL INSULATION SUPPLIES","200212"
"AVIS BUDGET GROUP","201110"
"HONEYWELL AEROSPACE","201307"
"AVIS BUDGET GROUP","201110"
"MERCK SHARP & DOHME","199608"
"PHARMA-BIO SERV INC","200803"
"UPS STORE","200407"
"PROCTER & GAMBLE","200403"
"W HOLDING CO INC","200712"
"AVIS BUDGET GROUP","201110"
```

I want to get the dates (last date of month) on the basis of last 2 character of second column, for this i use the command:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{A[01]="31";A[02]="28";A[03]="31";A[04]="30";A[05]="31";A[06]="30";A[07]="31";A[08]="31";A[09]="30";A[10]="31";A[11]="30";A[12]="31";}{ print $1, substr($2,2,6)A[substr($2,6,2)] }' order.txt
```

this is giving the output:

```
"Company" New Ad
"ELECTRICAL INSULATION SUPPLIES" 20021231
"AVIS BUDGET GROUP" 20111031
"HONEYWELL AEROSPACE" 201307
"AVIS BUDGET GROUP" 20111031
"MERCK SHARP & DOHME" 199608
"PHARMA-BIO SERV INC" 200803
"UPS STORE" 200407
"PROCTER & GAMBLE" 200403
"W HOLDING CO INC" 20071231
```

which is not extracting my result, what wrong i'm doing.

Comment: oops i got it, i need to make it like `A["03"]="31"` thanks

Comment: Your sample input would have been far more useful if you hadn't picked all dates that have 31 days. Someone could post a solution that always sets the number of days to 31 (or doesn't account for leap years or...) and it'd appear to work with your sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the number of days in February depends on whether a year is a leap year or not, the days per month depend on both the month and the year.

You can use the following `gawk` (GNU awk) script to achieve that:

*last_day.awk*:

```
function days_per_month(year, month) {
    date = year" "month" 31 00 00 00"
    day = strftime("%d", mktime(date))
    return 31-day%31
}

# On every line of input
{
    year = substr($2,2,4)
    month = substr($2,6,2)
    last_day = days_per_month(year, month)
    print $1, year""month""last_day
}
```

Call it like this:

```
gawk -F, -f last_day.awk order.csv
```

---

Btw, it is `gawk` specific because of the use of `mktime()` and `strftime()`

Comment: When you set a date like `31th of April`, you'll get the `1st of May`. With that day (`1`) you can use the modulo operator to get the last day of the previous month.

Comment: Huh. I had no idea mktime() would do that. I'd have expected it just to return `-1` for an invalid date. OK, good to know, thx.

Comment: :) That's the first time I showed something new to EdMorton! Leaving for 3 day vacation now. (need to hurry).. What a moment! :)

Answer (score 1):

try following awk command too, you need not to create an array by hardcoding its index values, we could create it by split command itself. Try following:

```
awk -F'[",]' '
BEGIN{
    split("31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31", month,",")
}
{
    month[2]=((substr($5,1,4)%4+0)==0 && (substr($5,1,4)%100+0!=0)) || (substr($5,1,4)%400+0==0)?29:28;
    val=substr($5,5,2)~/^0/?1:2;
    print substr($0,1,length($0)-1)\
          month[substr($0,length($0)-val,val)]\
          substr($0,length($0))
}
'  Input_file
```

This will take care of leap year feb month too.

Comment: Good idea, but not 100% correct. If the year is dividable be 100 it is not a leap year, except it is dividable by 400.

Comment: Apologies hek2mgl, could you please explain more on it, I didn't get it. Will be grateful to you.

Comment: Just look at [wikipedia - leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm). I also just found that out a moment ago.

Comment: Cool, have taken a look. I have changed my condition now and did few tests looks good to me, kindly do let me know your views on same.

Comment: Ok, looks good now + plus should work with any POSIX version of awk. Plus one. I'd probably also make it a function `is_leap_year()`. It would be more obvious what you are doing.

Comment: @EdMorton: actually printed a variable's value before making actual code, removed it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }
NR>1 {
    # Get the secs since epoch for the 1st of next month then subtract
    # 1 days worth of seconds to get the last day of this month
    nextMth = substr($4,5) % 12 + 1
    year = substr($4,1,4) + (nextMth == 1 ? 1 : 0)
    secs = mktime(year" "nextMth" 1 0 0 0") - 24*60*60
    $4 = strftime("%Y%m%d",secs)
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"Company","New Add Date"
"ELECTRICAL INSULATION SUPPLIES","20021231"
"AVIS BUDGET GROUP","20111031"
"HONEYWELL AEROSPACE","20130731"
"AVIS BUDGET GROUP","20111031"
"MERCK SHARP & DOHME","19960831"
"PHARMA-BIO SERV INC","20080331"
"UPS STORE","20040731"
"PROCTER & GAMBLE","20040331"
"W HOLDING CO INC","20071231"
"AVIS BUDGET GROUP","20111031"
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry folks, i was just making the mistake, now i corrected this. i think 0 was getting ignored, now i made those key as string

```
 awk -F, 'BEGIN{A["01"]="31";A["02"]="28";A["03"]="31";A["04"]="30";A["05"]="31";A["06"]="30";A["07"]="31";A["08"]="31";A["09"]="30";A["10"]="31";A["11"]="30";A["12"]="31";}{ print $1, substr($2,2,6)A[substr($2,6,2)] }' order.txt
```

Comment: What's with February in a leap year?